# Visual Studio is not seeing my altered templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates

So I am trying to create a multiple file template to using in visual studio 2010 C#.

I created an initial template using the visual studio export template wizard.

The problem I am having is when I extract the template and re-zip it visual studio no longer sees the template (note that I change nothing, I only unzip and zip)

Am I missing out a step or something?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more info about how you unzip&zip (code)?

Comment: No because that is all I do and it no longer shows up. I right click, extract, then I re-zip the folder and visual studio no longer sees the plugin. I do nothing else.

Comment: I have followed the microsoft steps to create a multiple file item template [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247115(v=vs.90).aspx) but like I said, I unzip a working template, re-zip it and now it no longer shows up in visual studio.

Comment: which zip tool are you using?

Comment: Right click folder -> Sent To -> Compressed (zipped) Folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

Trick is, instead of selecting the folder which is unzipped, open the folder and then select all the files inside and then zip it. This should work well.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had to selected the individual files to extract (just opened in a explorer window) and then I had to select the files (not the folder they are in) and re-zip. Thanks again